# Estimate number of registers required in GLSL shader

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader

Lately I'm getting some

> error C6020: Constant register limit exceeded at variable; more than 1024 registers needed to compile program

errors during compilation of a GLSL vertex shader, probably because of the number of uniform variables and I'm trying to figure out a way of estimating/calculating the number of registers required in the shader based on the uniforms that I have defined. Is there any guide or rule for that?

For example, am I correct to assume that variables up to vec4 in size require 1 register and mat4 require 4 registers?
Are there any rules for this purpose?

Comment: If you were hitting the uniform limit, the compiler/linker _should_ tell you that. In that case, you could switch to UBOs/SSBOs/TBOs to get your data to the shader. OpenGL does not have a concept of "registers", and therefore also no rules for that. You are running into some implementation-specific limit.

Comment: You're most likely trying to send a huge amount of data to uniforms. Try sending your data as a texture to a sampler instead?

Comment: Perhaps it isn't an uniform limit issue, but a too big struct in your GLSL code.

Comment: Its 100% because of a large array of mat4 matrices. The point of the question is to find out a way to quantify how close/far I am from the limitations, in order to find out what approach should I follow to resolve the issue. For example, I noticed that the matrices can be reduced to 3 vec4's isntead of a mat4. Is this gonna help at all? Also if I implement an UBO, are my current uniform variables and arrays replaced by only one uniform for the UBO? In other words, as long as don't exceed the max uniform buffersize, I'm free to include whatever I want in the struct?

Comment: Can you share the shader?

Comment: These comments helped me narrow down the problem as in my case I had a float4 morphedVerts[1023] that was breaking the shader. Lowering it to 1000 in size made the error go away and the shader compiles. Not really a best solution. Probably better to switch to other ways of passing data as @derhass said

Comment: ...especially wanting to avoid potential hardware dependency nightmares.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Graphics hardware is simply too diverse for any such estimation. Even your seemingly simple assumption:

> variables up to vec4 in size require 1 register and mat4 require 4 registers?

That's not correct on a lot of modern hardware. It used to be, but that was years ago. Especially if you're talking about individual `uniform` variables; compilers can play all kinds of games with them.

There is no even remotely accurate way of estimating the number of such resources consumed by a piece of GLSL code. You can count the number of uniform components your code uses, but that's because OpenGL tells you how to do it. Beyond that, there's nothing you can do.

Comment: So, this error is just an indication that you should just reduce the uniform consumption of the shader?

Comment: @GregK.: That seems to be what it's saying.